# Setting return value for mocked asyncio.coroutine

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-asyncio

I'm attempting to mock a helper method in a class I'm testing, but I'm unable to set the return value. It is instead `None`, which causes an error in the method making the call.

```
import unittest
import asyncio
import unittest.mock

class MyClass:

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def return_number(self):
        return 5

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def add_two(self):
        val = yield from self.return_number()
        return val + 2


class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.mc = MyClass()

    def test_add(self):
        val = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.mc.add_two())
        self.assertEqual(val, 7)

    def test_with_mock(self):
        """ Replace return_number with mocked method """
        mm = unittest.mock.MagicMock()
        mm.iter.return_value = 2
        self.mc.return_number = unittest.mock.Mock(return_value=mm)

        val = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.mc.add_two())
        self.assertEqual(val, 4)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Is there some way to mock `return_number` in this example such that it returns a specific value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do something similar:

```
def test_with_mock(self):
    """ Replace return_number with mocked method """
    with mock.patch.object(self.mc, "return_number", return_value=2):
        self.mc.return_number = asyncio.coroutine(self.mc.return_number)
        val = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.mc.add_two())
        self.assertEqual(val, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found one solution, though I'd prefer something similar to `test_with_mock` above, where I can set the return value manually rather than providing a function.

```
def test_with_patch(self):
    """ This one seems to work """
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def fake_ret_num(self):
        return 2

    with unittest.mock.patch.object(mc.MyClass, 'return_number', 
                                    fake_ret_num) as mock_meth:

        val = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.mc.add_two())
        self.assertEqual(val, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also benefit of [`aiounittest`](https://github.com/kwarunek/aiounittest) and use its `futurized`

Code to test:

```
# dummy_math.py

from asyncio import sleep

async def add(x, y):
    await sleep(666)
    return x + y
```

And the test using `AsyncTestCase` and futurized as a mock `return_value`:

```
from aiounittest import futurized, AsyncTestCase
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

import dummy_math

class MyTest(AsyncTestCase):

    def tearDown(self):
        super().tearDown()
        patch.stopall()

    async def test_add(self):
        mock_sleep = Mock(return_value=futurized('whatever'))
        patch('dummy_math.sleep', mock_sleep).start()
        ret = await dummy_math.add(5, 6)
        self.assertEqual(ret, 11)
        mock_sleep.assert_called_once_with(666)

    async def test_fail(self):
        mock_sleep = Mock(return_value=futurized(Exception('whatever')))
        patch('dummy_math.sleep', mock_sleep).start()
        with self.assertRaises(Exception) as e:
            await dummy_math.add(5, 6)
        mock_sleep.assert_called_once_with(666)
```